# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function in my query. It runs perfect id DTS 2008 but gives this error in SSIS 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @ColumnTotal             INT,
        @HTProcOfficeColumnNames NVARCHAR(4000),
        @TBLColumnNames          NVARCHAR(4000),
        @query                   NVARCHAR(4000),
        @subqueryInsert          NVARCHAR(4000),
        @subqueryValues          NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @ColumnTotal = Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT htprocoffice
        FROM   table
        WHERE  COLUMN NOT LIKE '% - CO'
        GROUP  BY COLUMN) T

SELECT @HTProcOfficeColumnNames = COALESCE(@HTProcOfficeColumnNames 
           + ',[' + htprocoffice + ']', '[' + htprocoffice + ']')
FROM   (SELECT htprocoffice
        FROM   table
        WHERE  COLUMN NOT LIKE '% - CO'
        GROUP  BY COLUMN) T
ORDER  BY COLUMN

SELECT @TBLColumnNames = COALESCE(@TBLColumnNames + ',' + NAME, NAME)
FROM   table
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id
              FROM   table
              WHERE  type = 'U'
                     AND NAME = 'TableName')
       AND NAME LIKE 'HTOffice%'
ORDER  BY NAME
```

Is there any error in the below code?

```
set @subqueryInsert = substring(@TBLColumnNames,1,@ColumnTotal*11-1) --The error occurs here but not sure though. 
set @subqueryInsert = 'INSERT INTO Table  
(RunDate,OrderBy,Period,IConOffice,IConOfficeType,'+ @subqueryInsert+')'
set @subqueryValues =  
replace(replace(@HTProcOfficeColumnNames,'[',''''), ']','''')
```

Comment: You should really start to indent / format your SQL properly.

Comment: How could we possibly answer this? It is all driven on the actual data found in your tables.

Comment: This was my first time posting a question. Sorry for any inconvenience. The Error part of the code is:  set @subqueryInsert = substring(@TBLColumnNames,1, @ColumnTotal*11-1)

Comment: Did you check if `@ColumnTotal` is returning `0` or `null` ?

Comment: Well what are the values in those variables? You're fetching them using totally different criteria from your table, so that sounds like the reason.

Comment: Well your error does occur where you think it does. Look at the values of `@TBLColumnNames` and `@ColumnTotal` and you'll see that, with the math you are doing, it won't make sense for the substring. i.e. `@ColumnTotal*11-1` is < 1 i'm betting....

Comment: @ColumnTotal is returning 0

Comment: Then you are passing -1 as the length parameter to substring which is invalid.

Comment: with the value of 6 for different table, its giving me same error

Comment: Seeing as it is data related, you need to determine what the actual values of your variables are when it goes bad. Wrap in error handling and log the values to table or file or similar. Then it should be relatively simple to work backwards.